# how to make a textbox or combobox only except three months name if other than 3 months (jan feb march) any other month entered it should give an error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

I am making a form where salaries are entered but salaries are entered only in the range of jan-mar so other than these months should not be accepted, while pressing the "Add" button which will update the form data to MYSQL database should give an error message saying month entered is not allowed
I am using visual studio 2019 visual basic .net

I really apologize for my weak English

Comment: So, add months in the range January-March to the ComboBox items. A User can only select these.

Comment: thanks for the answer okay that helps in combobox but what with the textbox how to control it there in textbox

Comment: To *control* what exactly? Aren't you using a ComboBox to select the Month?

Comment: Surely you know how to determine whether the value in a textbox is a legitimate value. That couldn't be more basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ValidatingEvent`. If you wish to inform the user of the error use the `ErrorProvider`.

```
Private err As New ErrorProvider()
Private Sub TextBox1_Validating(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Validating
    If TextBox1.Text = "January" OrElse TextBox1.Text = "February" OrElse TextBox1.Text = "March" Then
        err.Clear()
    Else
        e.Cancel = True
        err.SetError(TextBox1, "This text box months Jananuary - March")
    End If
End Sub
```